# export, bash command not found

Tags: bash, export

I have used export before but I don't know why when I set the variable PATH to any directory this time, ls, awk commands are not found but no problem with pwd, cd

```
export PATH="/Users/carolW/Desktop"

ls
-sh: ls: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
export PATH=/Users/carolW/Desktop:$PATH
```

You're removing all the normal directories from your path, so it only looks in your Desktop folder for everything. You just want to add your directory, not replace the entire path with it.

Comment: No need to `export` the variable `PATH` here, it's (very, _very_ likely) already marked as exported.

Comment: No need, but no harm either

Comment: in fact, I wanted to set a path directory and not the general path that I wrongly used. The purpose is to add the path directory to a file name to use further commands like cp

but export $curr_dir="/Users/carolW/Desktop" and then, ls $curr_dir/"header" or ls $curr_dir."/header" doesn't work. note that header is the name of the file in /Users/carolW/Desktop

Comment: A good idea is to use lowercase or CamelCase for your own variables. All the environment variables used by standard applications are UPPERCASE, so you won't accidentally conflict.

Comment: `ls $curr_dir/header` should work. `ls $curr_dir."/header"` won't work, since there's no `.` at the end of the directory name.

Comment: ls $curr_dir/header doesn't work
ls: ~/Desktop/header: No such file or directory

Comment: Why is it saying `~/Desktop` when you put `/Users/carolW/Desktop` in the variable?

Comment: In one trial, I put ~/Desktop. I changed it to the full path from the root, /Users…, and now, it works.

Another problem is that I want to copy the content of the header file in a file that I created but there is a small problem:

cp $curr_dir/header $FILE."rtf";

but I get ? before the extension rtf. Why? Is it because ""?

Comment: If you're getting a strange character, it must be in the value of `$FILE`. Quotes just prevent special characters from being processed, you don't need them around `rtf`.

Comment: If you write `curr_dir=~/Desktop` it will work. When you put the variable in quotes, it prevents `~` from being expanded, so you need to write the full path from the root.

Comment: the values of FILE comes from for FILE in $(awk '{print $2}' my_file). The values of FILE are therefore the strings (alphanumeric,-,_), 1 per line. Is perhaps \n or carriage return that causes the problem? Unlikely.

precisely,

for FILE in $(awk '{print $2}' my_file)
do
 cp $curr_dir/header $FILE."rtf";
done

Comment: No, newlines get turned into spaces by `$(...)`. What does `ls -b *.rtf` show? It should show special characters as escape sequences instead of `?`.

Comment: It sounds like you created `my_file` on a Windows machine, so it uses `\r\n` as the newline instead of `\n`. So the `\r` characters are included in the `awk` output.

Comment: Use `tr -d '\r' my_file > new_file` to get rid of those characters.

Comment: well I create too many such files as there are many in the input and output of awk to be created. Is there any other solution otherwise the directory will be flooded by files?

Comment: `sed -i 's/\r$//' *` will fix up all the files in the current directory in place.

Comment: sed -i 's/\r$//' *
sed: 1: "my_file\r.rtf": invalid command code L


same output for 
sed -i 's/\?$//' *

Comment: The `-i` option requires a parameter, to specify the extension to give a backup file. So it should be `sed -i .bak 's/\r$//' *` if you want backup files, or `sed -i '' 's/\r$//' *` if you want to live dangerously.

Answer (score 0):

most probably because pwd and cd are built shell command
(you can test: 
    which pwd
    which ls
)
However, ls are such are tools you can find in /bin directory or such, and those paths are defined in your variable PATH.
If you clear the variable PATH, most likely you won't find your tool anymore.

You may use export PATH=$PATH:"/Users/carolW/Desktop"
So that you concatenate your path to the already existing paths

Comment: Better put your personal paths at the beginning of `PATH` so as to be able to override commands with your own! Otherwise, you just plain can't.